# python cv2.findNonZero pixels considering alpha value of the pixels

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image with most of the pixel values as `(0,0,0)` and alpha value `1`, with exception of some pixels containing crucial information.

Example, in the image below of shape `(1280wx800hx4c)` there are three kinds of pixels

```
 a. pixel value (0,0,0) alpha=1 (indicating fully transparent)
 b. pixel value (0,0,0) alpha=255 (black background)
 c. data pixels (1 IAS_FLAP_APP_SPEED)
```

[image: Input Image]

Using opencv-python cv2.findNonZero pixels I was able to get the non zero pixels and cropped the image.
**Code**:

```
import cv2, numpy

golden_rehost_image = r"C:\Project_Files\Python_Scripts\vis_auto\input.png"
vista_rehost_image = r"C:\Project_Files\Python_Scripts\vis_auto\input.png"

# read golden image
gi_read = cv2.imread(golden_rehost_image, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# assuming that golden_rehost_image image is of 4 channels
# you find that by gi_read.shape (the third coordinate is number of channels)
# change that to single channels

print (gi_read.shape)
# output: (800,1280,4)

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(gi_read, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print (gray_image.shape)
# output: (800, 1280)

# find non zero pixels in gray_image
nonzeropixels = cv2.findNonZero(gray_image)


#  X axis is horizontal axis (left to right)
#  Y axis is vertical axis (top to bottom)

x1,x2 = nonzeropixels[0][0][0], nonzeropixels[-1][0][0]
y1,y2 = nonzeropixels[0][0][1], nonzeropixels[-1][0][1]

print (f"(x1,x2) = ({x1,x2}), (y1,y2) = ({y1,y2})")
# output: (x1,x2)=(685,837), (y1,y2) = (113,129)

# crop vista_rehost_image using these nonzeropixels and display the cropped
vi_read = cv2.imread(vista_rehost_image)

cropped_imag = vi_read[y1:y2, x1:x2]

cv2.imshow("cropped", cropped_imag)
cv2.waitKey(0) 

cv2.imwrite("C:\Project_Files\cropped_image.png",cropped_imag)
```

Output of this code- cropped_image:
[image: cropped_image]

In the cropped image, I see that most of the black background and half the important text is lost. So I was wondering is there a better way to extract pixels with alpha value other than 1

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should fit an oobb to this points (via cv2.boundingRect) and then use this box, because it contains all points, rather than just first and last one. Also masking out points under certain transparency threshold during gray-scale conversion would probably be desirable